# Implicit do loop array initialization

Tags: arrays, initialization, fortran

I want to initialize an array on one line with an *implicit do loop*. However, I always get a syntax or shape error. Can anyone help me correct the following construct?

```
integer myarray :: (maxdim, nr)

myarray(1:maxdim,nr) = (/ (/i,i=1,maxdim/),nr /)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are initializing an array with `MAXDIM` rows and `NR` columns, and it looks like each column contains the integers 1 to `MAXDIM`.

As a first step, go ahead and write out the actual `DO`-loop:

```
do j=1,NR
    do i=1,MAXDIM
        myarray(i,j) = i
    end do
end do
```

Collapse the inner loop to an implicit loop structure:

```
do j = 1,NR
    myarray(1:MAXDIM,j) = (/ (i, i=1,MAXDIM) /)
end do
```

When we try to collapse the outer loop, though, something strange happens:

```
myarray = (/ ((/ (i, i=1,MAXDIM) /), j=1,NR) /)
```

Now, I get an incompatible ranks error as you did.  Since I'm not very good at the implicit do-loops either, I looked at the `shape` intrinsic results for the array constructor:

```
print *, shape(myarray)
print *, shape((/ ((/ (i, i=1,MAXDIM) /), j=1,NR) /))
```

This prints out

```
   5      10
  50
```

The array constructor is simply expanding a 1-D array , flattening any nested array constructions.  We can actually drop the second set of `(/ /)` to simplify.  Since everything is already in the proper order, we can use the `reshape` intrinsic to ensure proper rank.  My full test program is then:

```
program sotest
    implicit none

    integer, parameter :: MAXDIM = 5
    integer, parameter :: NR     = 10

    integer :: i
    integer :: j
    integer :: myarray(MAXDIM, NR)
    integer :: myarray_implicit(MAXDIM, NR)

    do j = 1,NR
        do i = 1,MAXDIM
            myarray(i,j) = i
        end do
    end do 

    myarray_implicit = reshape((/ ((i,i=1,MAXDIM), j=1,NR) /), (/ MAXDIM, NR /))

    print *, all(myarray == myarray_implicit)
 end program sotest
```

Comment: Note that it is also valid to write

  `myarray_implicit = reshape((/ ((i,i=1,MAXDIM), j=1,NR) /), shape(myarray_implicit))`

to avoid explicitly typing out the dimensions of your matrix again.

Comment: It's odd that one can't initialize a 2D array implicitly. I feel like this ought to be a bug in Fortran rather than a feature. (With a decade of Fortran experience, I'm getting used to that....)

Answer (score 7):

The implicit do loop will only create a vector so you'll have to reshape that.  Something like this:

```
integer, dimension(m,n) :: myarray
integer :: ix, jx
...
myarray = reshape( [ (ix, ix = 1, m*n) ], [ m, n ] )
```

or perhaps you want a more complicated, nested, implied-do loop:

```
myarray = reshape( [ ((ix+jx, ix = 1, m), jx = 1, n) ], [ m, n ] )
```

Note that I'm using the Fortran2003 convention of `[ ]` to delimit array constructions, rather than `(/ /)`.  Note also that you have to declare the implied do loop index variables.