# Fortran loop for discrete values

Tags: fortran, fortran95

Is there any way to run a loop for discrete values of a variable? What about in some latest version?

Something like

```
for i in 1  5 9 11  31 77
```

used in Unix shell script?

Comment: Someone is trying to write a [tag:pascal] program in [tag:fotran].

Comment: I agree, should be able to say `DO I=(/ 1,3,5,7 /)` but you can't. Maybe it can be done with in [implicit do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070528/implicit-do-loop-array-initialization). I will investigate.

Comment: @ja72: your assertion that someone is trying to write a Pascal program in Fortran is strange, Pascal provides no more support for 'looping' over an arbitrary list of numbers than Fortran does.  Furthermore, OP indicates that she has drawn inspiration from Unix shell scripting.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark in pascal you can loop over an `emum` with non sequential values. They have to be constants though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
integer, dimension (5) :: indx = [5, 9, 11, 31, 71]

do i=1, size(indx)
   j=indx(i)
   ....
end do
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an implied do loop to accomplish this, but you'll have to define the array of values as above:

```
integer, dimension (5) :: indx = [5, 9, 11, 31, 71]
integer, dimension (5) :: rslt 
integer, external      :: func
rslt = (/ func(indx(j)), j=1,5 /)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps, but you can use arrays for indeces

```
program Console1

implicit none

! Variables
INTEGER :: X(4) = (/ 1, 3, 5, 7 /)
REAL :: Y(10) = 0.0

! Body of Console1
print *, X
!   1   3   5   7
Y(X) = 10.0/X
print *, Y
!   10.0    0.0    3.33   0.0    2.00   0.0    1.428    0.0 ...

end program Console1
```